# Why can't display data that has been stored in WebSQL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-sql

What's wrong with my function? function getCart can't display data stored in WebSQL. But my function addToCart works and can store data to WebSQL. Please help me if you know my false.

```
angular.module('login').factory('CartService',
    ['$webSql', '$http', '$q', 'urls',
        function ($webSql, $http, $q, urls) {
            var factory = {
                initdb: initdb, 
                addToCart: addToCart,
                getCart: getCart
            };

            var db = null;

            return factory

            function initdb(){
                db = openDatabase('CART', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
                db.transaction(function(transaction){
                    transaction.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cart (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, price DOUBLE)");
                });
            }

            function addToCart(name, price){
                    var item = {
                            "name" : name,
                            "price" : price
                    }
                    console.log('Success add cart');

                    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                        transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO cart (name, price) VALUES (?, ?)", [name, price]);
                           getCart();
                        });
                }

            function getCart(name){
                var item = {
                        "name" : name
                }

                db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                    transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM cart name = ?", [name]);
                    });
            }
    }
    ]);
```

Comment: you need to implement callback handler for executeSql to see the fetched records from websql db.

Comment: in my getCart function sir?

Comment: Yes, I have just added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *implement callback handler* for `executeSql` (3rd parameter after `[name]`) to see the fetched records from **websql db**.

Try this

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM cart name = ?", [name], function(tx, rs) {
        var resultSet =  rs.rows;
        for ( var counter = 0; counter < resultSet.length; counter++ )
        {
            console.log( resultSet.item(counter) );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @CesarWahyu did the code worked? If yes, then accept and upvote the answer that has helped you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work